# Styling innerHTML output

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling

I'm trying to create a JavaScript program using the innerHTML function wherein the user types in the first and last names of somebody in two text-boxes and the the JavaScript manipulates the names after clicking a button to the following format:

> Last Name, First Name.

I have successfully gotten the names to appear 'onclick' in that order, but the output looks like this:

> Dick
>
> ,
>
> Philip
>
> .

I want everything to be on one line without breaks.  I have already tried creating a css class that would affect the div: .nobr { white-space:nowrap; } This didn't work, however.

The HTML that I'm working with so far looks like this:

```
    <div id='displayName2'></div>,<div id='displayName1'></div>.
```

Comment: Use <span> in place of <div>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get those two `<div>` tags to appear without a linebreak in between, use the CSS attribute `display: inline;`  Or, use `<span>` tags instead of `<div>`, since `<span>` is displayed inline by default, where `<div>` is a block element. Semantically, `<span>` is probably more appropriate., but if you cannot change the HTML, modify your CSS accordingly:

```
<div id='displayName2'></div>,<div id='displayName1'></div>

#displayName2, #displayName1 {
   display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `<span>`s instead of `<div>`s for this purpose.

If you insist on using `<div>`s, then use `display: inline` to make the `<div>`s render as inline elements.

Answer (score 3):

Better use `<span>` instead of `<div>`, it also has neutral semantic meaning and it's inline by default.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options. `div` elements are `display: block` by default. Either use `span`s instead of divs or style your divs using `display: inline`.